# Converting HTML.EditorFor into a drop down (html.dropdownfor?)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, html-helper, editorfor

Currently I am using a Html.EditorFor control in a default 'Create' View page like this.

```
 <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsActive) %>
```

I would like to convert this to a drop down with values and still be binded to the model in the view. My question is two fold.

1. If there are only 2/3 values needed in the drop down..Is there a quick way to explicitly populate 2 or 3 values?
2. If the list is big and needs to come from a sql query, how to do this?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In order to generate a dropdownlist you need 2 properties on your view model: a scalar property to bind the selected value to and a collection property which will contain the items to show in the dropdown.

So you could define a view model:

```
public class DropDownListViewModel
{
    public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

and then on your main view model have a property of this type:

```
public DropDownListViewModel Foo { get; set; }
```

Now you could have a custom editor template for this type (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/DropDownListViewModel.ascx`):

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<DropDownListViewModel>" 
%>
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedValue, Model.Items) %>
```

and then in your main view:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo) %>
```

Now all that's left is to have your controller action rendering the main view to fill the `Foo` property with the corresponding values. The could be hardcoded, come from a repository or whatever. It doesn't really matter.

On the other hand if you knew the values in advance you could hardcode them in the editor template (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/YesNoDropDown.ascx`):

```
<%= Html.DropDownList(
    "", 
    new SelectList(
        new[] 
        { 
            new { Value = "true", Text = "Yes" },
            new { Value = "false", Text = "No" },
        }, 
        "Value", 
        "Text",
        Model
    )
) %>
```

and then:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.IsActive, "YesNoDropDown") %>
```

or by decorating the IsActive property on your view model:

```
[UIHint("YesNoDropDown")]
public bool IsActive { get; set; }
```

and then:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.IsActive) %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I am getting a Identifier expected exception in the editor template .ascx page...near new[]

Comment: @ZVenue, still problems with this one?

Comment: No more problems.. thanks for your help.. Your Modified solution here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568111/problems-converting-editorfor-to-dropdownlist

Comment: I noticed when I did this approach validation broke.  did you experience the  same issue?

Comment: I am a bit confused on using a @html.editorFor and the answer given above..  My validation is failing and I figure there is a simple reason why, but I am just not figuring it out.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: I kind of knew this already, but it was helpful to see it presented in such a clear and concise way. Thanks Darin.