# Identifier expected error in ascx page in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I am getting BC30203 error in my ascx page.

BC30203: Identifier expected. (Line 4 - new[] )

Code:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList(
"", 
new SelectList(
    new[] 
    { 
        new { Value = "true", Text = "Yes" },
        new { Value = "false", Text = "No" },
    }, 
    "Value", 
    "Text",
    Model
)
) %>
```

What is missing ?

Comment: Solution here.. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568111/problems-converting-editorfor-to-dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

You are missing what to create:

```
new SelectList(
new ListItem[] 
{ 
    new ListItem { Value = "true", Text = "Yes" },
    new ListItem { Value = "false", Text = "No" },
}
```

When using the `new` keyword, you must tell the compiler what you want to create it won't take a guess.

Comment: I am still getting same error.. Please see this post to see where I am coming from... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517627/converting-html-editorfor-into-a-drop-down-html-dropdownfor

Answer (score 0):

A red-flag that I see is that you are not giving a name to your SelectList.

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("MySelect", 
new SelectList(
new[] 
{ 
 new SelectListItem() { Value = "true", Text = "Yes" },
 new SelectListItem() { Value = "false", Text = "No" },
}, 
"Value", 
"Text",
Model
)
) %>
```

Comment: It still does not like it.. i am getting same error with your code

Comment: Do you know why you are specifying "Model" in the **selectedValue** parameter? I'm not sure whether or not that that is causing your error, but my gut says that you are not using that parameter correctly. In the troubleshooting spirit, remove the last three params **"Value","Text",Model** - Does the error persist?

Answer (score 0):

The DropDownList method requires an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` as the 2nd parameter.

Try something like this

```
<%= Html.DropDownList(
   "Name",
   new List<SelectListItem>()    
   { 
       new SelectListItem() { Value = "true", Text = "Yes" },
       new SelectListItem() { Value = "false", Text = "No" },
   },
   "Value",
   Model
)
) %>
```

Comment: SelectList inherits IEnumerable<SelectListItem>