# Drop down box in edit.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am creating an ASP.NET MVC 3 application which references a database and within the Edit.cshtml file I wish to limit the edit function of one of the items (Score) to simply be either 0,1,2,3,4. I have tried the options in this post [Converting HTML.EditorFor into a drop down (html.dropdownfor?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517627/converting-html-editorfor-into-a-drop-down-html-dropdownfor) but cannot seem to get it working.

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Score)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Score, "YesNoDropDown")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Score)
    </div>
```

Many thanks.

Chri3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't forsee it needing to be changed often, I'd just use a static select like below:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Score)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <select id="score" name="score">
    @for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
         <option value="@i" @(Model.Score==i ? " selected": "")>@i</option>
    }
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

to use Html.DropDownListFor, you need to pass in the argument of type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.

Here i've created some mockup for you

in Model

```
public class SampleModel
    {
        public string SeletectRateItem { get; set; }
        public IList<SelectListItem> RateItem
        {
            get
            {
                var item = new List<SelectListItem>();
                item.Add(new SelectListItem(){Selected = false, Text = "1", Value = "1"});
                item.Add(new SelectListItem(){Selected = false, Text = "2", Value = "2"});
                item.Add(new SelectListItem(){Selected = false, Text = "3", Value = "3"});
                item.Add(new SelectListItem(){Selected = false, Text = "4", Value = "4"});
                item.Add(new SelectListItem(){Selected = false, Text = "5", Value = "5"});
                return item;
            }
        }
    }
```

and in cshtml

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SeletectRateItem, Model.RateItem)
```

Comment: Hi @Raver0124 thank you for you comment, it is saying that the <SelectListItem> could not be found. Please excuse my amatuerism I am trying to learn. Thanks again.

Comment: no prob, you just need to import namespace. "using System.Web.Mvc; " on top of the page